# adding javascript to tpl file from template.php

Tags: theming

```
<?php
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/my_js_file.js', 'theme');
?>
```

I want to add a javascript file just to the tpl file titled

```
views-view--gurus--page-1.tpl.php
```

I have this code to enter it to a specific them but what about just a certain tpl file.

I am guessing something like this

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/my_js_file.js', 'view');
```

Comment: You can add it in your tpl file too using drupal_add_js. Just flush your caches and it should show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using. I don't know if this will have any gotchas in future where the template file I want is in the array but not actually used. So far it's working flawlessly.

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $templates = $vars['template_files'];
    if (in_array('page-node-add-discipline', $templates)) {
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/create_discipline.js');
        $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
    }
}
```

Put that in your template.php

Comment: I edited it with the whole function. That's copy pasted from my code just with the theme name changed.